# How to load data from local machine to hdfs using flume

Tags: hadoop, flume

i am new to flume so please tell me...how to store log files from my local machine to local my HDFS using flume
i have issues in setting classpath and flume.conf file

Thank you,
ajay

Comment: what did you try exactly, and what's the error/problem you're encountering?

Comment: @peter sir thank you for your response... i have 1 ".tsv" file, I tried to load that file into hdfs using flume, now am getting error like this "if you have conf file you must include it in flume class path". i followed user guide and aaron kimball flume videos

Answer (score 1):

```
agent.sources = weblog
agent.channels = memoryChannel
agent.sinks = mycluster

## Sources #########################################################  
agent.sources.weblog.type = exec  
agent.sources.weblog.command = tail -F REPLACE-WITH-PATH2-your.log-FILE  
agent.sources.weblog.batchSize = 1  
agent.sources.weblog.channels =
REPLACE-WITH-
CHANNEL-NAME

## Channels ########################################################  
agent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory  
agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 100 agent.channels.memoryChannel.transactionCapacity = 100   

## Sinks ###########################################################   
agent.sinks.mycluster.type =REPLACE-WITH-CLUSTER-TYPE  
agent.sinks.mycluster.hdfs.path=/user/root/flumedata  
agent.sinks.mycluster.channel =REPLACE-WITH-CHANNEL-NAME
```

Save this file as logagent.conf and run with below command

```
# flume-ng agent –n agent –f logagent.conf &
```

Answer (score 0):

We do need more information to know why things are working for you.

The short answer is that you need a Source to read your data from (maybe the spooling directory source), a Channel (memory channel if you don't need reliable storage) and the HDFS sink.

*Update*

The OP reports receiving the error message, "you must include conf file in flume class path".

You need to provide the conf file as an argument. You do so with the `--conf-file` parameter. For example, the command line I use in development is:
`bin/flume-ng agent --conf-file /etc/flume-ng/conf/flume.conf --name castellan-indexer --conf /etc/flume-ng/conf`

The error message reads that way because the `bin/flume-ng` script adds the contents of the `--conf-file` argument to the classpath before running Flume.

Comment: sir thank you for your response...i took one ".tsv" file as source and i set flume master,node,sink exactly.when i tried to load that file into hdfs am encountering following "you must include conf file in flume class path"....so i don't know how to solve this and i am following flume user guide and aaron kimball's videos....please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you are appending data to your local file, you can use an exec source with "tail -F" command. If the file is static, use cat command to transfer the data to hadoop.

The overall architecture would be:

Source: Exec source reading data from your file

Channel : Either memory channel or file channel

Sink: Hdfs sink where data is being dumped.

Use user guide to create your conf file (https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html)

Once you have your conf file ready, you can run it like this:

```
bin/flume-ng agent -n $agent_name -c conf -f conf/your-flume-conf.conf
```